# Is there a general name for matrices which only have zeros on their main diagonal?

Tags: matrices, terminology

A diagonal matrix is one where every component not on the main diagonal is zero. E.g.
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
12 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -2
\end{array}
$$
Is there a term for matrices where every component on the main diagonal is zero? E.g.
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 3 & 5\\
-2 & 0 & 13\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
$$

Comment: The first ones are a subset of the set of [diagonally dominant matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix). The seconds ones are (almost!) non-diagonally dominant matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recall any name for this *class* of matrices, but such a matrix is usually called *a matrix with a zero diagonal*.

Comment: This term will do, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The precise definition is the **hollow matrix**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollow_matrix